# Suggestions for alternative 3D space partition tessellation, different from Voronoi and Delaunay

Tags: c++, python, delaunay, voronoi, tessellation

I have a system of mono-disperse spheres inside a cubic box. I am studying the volume distribution inside the sample, after tessellating it with either Voronoi and Delaunay tessellations.  I am interested on some properties which should not depend on the tessellation.

Currently, I am comparing with the values obtained from Voronoi and Delaunay. I would like to know if you are familiar with another space partition approach (It is important that the final sum of the individual cells add up to the total volume, and the cells should be disjoint). Furthermore, in case you know another kind of tessellation, do you also know a library which already implements it, preferable in C/C++ or python?

Some variations, like Laguerre partitions, coincide with my current Voronoi approach since the spheres are mono-disperse. Another candidate will be the Centroidal Voronoi tessellation, although I have not found yet a library to do that (although it could lead to evenly spaced cells which does not reflect the disorder inside the system, which is not desirable).

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: That's a very interesting question. Have you tried asking on cs.stackexchange.com as well?

Comment: What are you tessellating exactly? The pointwise tessellation of the sphere centers? What properties are required for the new tessellation? Would a simple octree suffice?

Comment: @DarrenEngwirda I am tessellating a system of monodisperse spheres. For Voronoi, each tessellation cell will be centered on the center of the sphere and will enclose it. For the Delaunay tessellation, the tessellation points are the centers of the spheres. Could you please elaborate on the "simple octree" suggestion, please? I need to finally partition the volume of the packing with disjoint tessellation cells.

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14045/755

Comment: @didierc, asking the same question simultaneously on two StackExchange sites is strongly discouraged.  For future reference, please suggest that people migrate their question rather than cross-posting on separate sites.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is partly about computer science (and has been reposted on [cs.se]) and partly a library recommendation request (which is not accepted on [so]).

Comment: I have asked the moderator to make the migration. I am sorry for the mistake. I knew it is not encouraged to duplicate question and for that reason I explicitly warned about it at cs. Thanks to @D.W. for illustrating me on how to ask for migration. At the end, I hope to get some answer to the question.

Comment: @D.W. my bad, I didn't realize what I was suggesting. I will keep this in mind.